# how to run jenkins declarative pipeline on node selected via parameter and label option

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I want to run a pipeline with the node set as parameter via the Node and Label plugin.
[image: run with parameters screenshot]

How do I change the declarative pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent  {
        label 'whatever'
    }
...
```

to use EXECUTION_NODE as agent to execute the pipeline? This seems to be much more complicated than I thought, or I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this: to present you the "Build with parameters" page, Jenkins needs to run your pipeline and parse its parameters. To run a pipeline, Jenkins needs a node. To have a node, it parses your pipeline. So the node is already selected by the time the dialog is shown. Moreover, in declarative pipeline all the nodes of all the stages get selected in the beginning.

You can try running a scripted pipeline or a combination of scripted and declarative, by running `node` and supplying `params.EXECUTION_NODE` as label. Scripted pipeline executes the script line by line.

Edit: this is working:

```
NODE = null
echo "This should be Null: $NODE"

node() {
    stage("Define node") {
        NODE = params.NODE
        echo "This is now $NODE"
    }
}
    
pipeline {
    agent { node { label "$NODE" }}
    parameters { string(name: 'NODE', defaultValue: 'some_node', description: '') }
    stages {
        stage("Main") {
            steps {
                echo "Hi"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an output of a second run with 'master' as parameter:

```
Started by user marat 
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] echo
This should be Null: null
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /home/jenkins/workspace/test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Define node)
[Pipeline] echo
This is now master
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] node
Running on master in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Main)
[Pipeline] echo
Hi
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: this is sad, and yes I see the internals of the implementation are striking against an easy solution, but the use case seems so basic that it is unclear why something like this is not supported with the nice declarative pipeline logic

Comment: Updated with working example. Note you need to run it twice.

Comment: i cannot get it to work. i have a parameter EXECUTION_NODE, I changed your script to refer to it as:

NODE = null
echo "This should be Null: $NODE"

node() {
    stage("Define node") {
        NODE = params.EXECUTION_NODE
        echo "This is now $NODE"
    }
}
    
pipeline {
    agent { node { label "$NODE" }}
    parameters { string(name: 'NODE', defaultValue: 'some_node', description: '') }
    stages {
        stage("Main") {
            steps {
               ...
it outputs:
This should be Null: null ..
 This is now null

Comment: Did you read my previous comment? "Note you need to run it twice."

Comment: i think I ran it twice

Comment: Updated my answer with a result of a successful (second) run. As you can see, it ran on the node I provided as parameter.