# Jenkins get Environment variable form calling shell script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In a Jenkinsfile, I am trying to set an environment variable by using withCredentials to call a shell script to return a list of data. I want to use this environment variable to populate a drop-down list.

```
environment {
    withCredentials([
                     usernamePassword(
                         credentialsId: "aws-creds",
                         usernameVariable: "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID",
                         passwordVariable: "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
                     )
                 ]) {
                      AWS_DATA =  sh 'aws ec2 describe-security-groups --region my-region | grep "xxxx" | sort -u | cut -d\" -f4'
                     }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
B

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62568693/2047614

Comment: You should likely append to the `env` map instead of trying to use the block. That would be much easier.