# Dynamic Node selection

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

We have multiple jenkins (freestyle ) jobs . These jobs are called in jenkins pipeline having define node in the variable.
Now how to run these job on specific node. That node specification will be define in the pipeline job.
How we can achieve this?
We tried with Node and label plugins however it is getting trigger on master node. Any suggestion or help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62568693/2047614

Answer (score 0):

Declarative pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        {your_agent_definition}
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Scripted pipeline:

```
node("your_agent_definition") {
    stage("Test"){
        ...
    }
}
```